# Filesystem-layout for postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Please advise with filesystem-layout to choose for PostgreSQL-Databases.

Assuming that wal is enabled. What filesystems should be built, which ones can be placed into the same FS?

I do not think it makes sense to make a file-system for every directory...

OS=RHEL 8, PG = 13

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking exactly. Something about the filesystem. But what exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter look at the answer from Laurenz. Better ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best is to have three file systems:

- one for the data directory
- one for the log files (`log_directory`)
- one for `pg_wal`

That reduced the risk of PostgreSQL crashing if either data files or log fill the disk. If you have them on different devices, it also helps to spread the I/O load.